Getting the YearMonth values between two LocalDate
I have two LocalDate values.
Say:
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1);
LocalDate endDate =  LocalDate.of(2024, 1, 31);

I need to determine the actual month values (in a List, for example) that are entirely or partially within this date range.
I am struggling to find a succinct way to do this.
A List of java.time.YearMonth would work, but so would a list of Strings.
All similar questions I have seen only address the number of months in between the dates, and not getting the actual month values themselves.

SequencedSet < YearMonth > months = startDate.datesUntil( endDate ).map( YearMonth :: from ).collect( TreeSet :: new , Set :: addAll , Set :: addAll ) — Sets eliminate duplicates. A SequencedSet like TreeSet maintains a particular encounter order.

There are many ways to do this.  You can use month and get String values of the date or YearMonth and get yyyy-mm values.   Adding 1 day to endDate to make the range inclusive.   List<YearMonth> month =startDate.datesUntil(endDate.plusDays(1)).map(YearMonth::from).distinct().toList();

It's a simple loop:
List<YearMonth> months = new ArrayList<>();
for (var date = startDate; !date.isAfter(endDate); date = date.plusMonths(1)) {
    months.add(YearMonth.from(date));
}


Correct. I‘d probably convert start and end to YearMonth first and then loop over YearMonths.
